# How to read a multi line using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read my data.txt file which looks like and store it in an array called buffer[i][j]

1 1 1 1

2 2 2 2

3 3 3 3

4 4 4 4

I am writing a code which looks like

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

int main() {

  FILE *fp1;
  int i,j;

  int buffer[4][4]={0};

  fp1 = fopen("exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc","r");

  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
      fscanf(fp1,"%d", &buffer[i][j]);
    }
    // fscanf(fp1,"\n");
  }
  fclose(fp1);

  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
      printf("%d ",buffer[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

but i get the output...

1 1 2 1

5 1 6 1

17 1 18 1

21 1 22 1

why????

Comment: What happens if you replace the "read file section" with `"%d %d %d %d"` and `&buffer[i][j]` with `&buffer[i][0]`, `&buffer[i][1]`, etc.

Comment: Please, tell me what does **exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc** mean?

Comment: it shud hav been data.txt. i forgot to change the file name... error on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Always* check the result of [`fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) to ensure the file has been opened.
- *Always* check the result of [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to ensure it was successful and prevent subsequent code processing variables that may not have been assigned a value (it returns the number of assignments made).
- Add a leading space character to the format specifier to skip whitespace, including newline characters: `" %d"`.

The code will treat a single line with sixteen `int`s the same as four lines with four `int`s. If it is important that the format of the file is four `int`s per line then read a single line using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then use `sscanf()` to extract the `int`s with the `%n` format specifier to ensure full buffer was processed:

```
int ints[4][4] = { { 0 } };
char buffer[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 4 && fgets(buffer, 1024, fp); i++)
{
    int pos;
    if (sscanf(buffer,
               "%d %d %d %d%n",
               &ints[i][0],
               &ints[i][1],
               &ints[i][2],
               &ints[i][3],
               &pos) != 4 || pos != strlen(buffer) - 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format: <%s>\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Only answer so far that addresses all the problems with the code.

Comment: As always, I agree better to use fgets() to read the line then sscanf() to parse the "words" into variables.

Answer (score 1):

To get required output (1111,2222,...) change:

```
fp1 = fopen("exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc","r");
```

to:

```
fp1 = fopen("data.txt","r");
```

**Clarification:** when using `fopen` you should write the name of file you want to read. In you case you have to write `data.txt`, not `exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc`... 
There is no file with this name, moreover there is no any data like 1 1 1 1, 2 2 2 2, 3 3 3 3, 4 4 4 4...

***For more detailes visit:***
    [**wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/fopen**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/fopen)

---

Here is your "modified" (excess/waste/extra `{` `}` removed and `data.txt` is written) code that gives you required output: 1 1 1 1, 2 2 2 2, 3 3 3 3, 4 4 4 4.
It prints the array named `buffer`. It means that...

...**data was successfully copied! from** `"data.txt"` **to** `buffer[4][4]`:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    int i,j;

    int buffer[4][4];

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            buffer[i][j] = 0;


    fp1 = fopen("data.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            fscanf(fp1,"%d", &buffer[i][j]);

    fclose(fp1);


    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            printf("%d ",buffer[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

---

***P.S.***

If `data.txt` will contain not

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

but

```
1 1 1    1
2   2   2 2
3       3 3 3
4 444    // the last two elements are absent
```

the program will read 1-st, 2-nd and 3-rd line properly, and the output of the 4-th line will be

```
4 444 0 0
```

It prints `4`, then `444`, and then `0` and `0`: the last two elements are '0's because `buffer` had been initialized by zeros, so all elements changed their values, but the last two remained to be zeros.

Comment: I don´t doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: I have written data.txt instead of exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc and I got the required output: 1 1 1 1, 2 2 2 2, 3 3 3 3, 4 4 4 4.

Maybe, I don't understand the problem properly.
I don't say that my answer provides the best solution, but it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add space at the beginning of the string format it should be `" %d"` to avoid the newline problems

```
fscanf(fp1," %d", &buffer[i][j]);
```

BTW you could use the following code instead

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
   fscanf(fp1," %d %d %d %d", &buffer[i][0], &buffer[i][1], &buffer[i][2], &buffer[i][3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have said you want to read `data.txt` then why are you opening the file `exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc`

Try changing this

```
fp1 = fopen("exact_enumerated_config_442_cub_mc","r");
```

to

```
fp1 = fopen("data.txt","r");
```